# Why merge sort with multiple strings using strcmp is not a proper method

Tags: c

I am trying to external merge multiple files that contain sorted string(base 
on strcmp)
but I encounter a problem when using external merge sort .

It seems that my merge sort method is not properly functioning , though the data is proper read into the`mergeSort()`,and the algorithm is just a typical iterative merge , I think maybe because that the strcmp is not proper in this case of sorting?

and the code below is the segment of my code and
I have changed the external merge to internal merge to test it ,but it still not working.

```
/* Iterative C program for merge sort */
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

/* Function to merge the two haves arr[l..m] and arr[m+1..r] of array arr[] */
void merge(char  arr[][300], int l, int m, int r);
// Utility function to find minimum of two integers
int min(int x, int y) { return (x<y)? x :y; }
/* Iterative mergesort function to sort arr[0...n-1] */
void mergeSort(char arr[][300], int n )
{
   int curr_size;  // For current size of subarrays to be merged
                   // curr_size varies from 1 to n/2
   int left_start; // For picking starting index of left subarray
                   // to be merged
   for (curr_size=1; curr_size<= n-1 ; curr_size = 2 * curr_size ){
       // Pick starting point of different subarrays of current size
       for ( left_start=0 ; left_start < n-1 ; left_start += 2 * curr_size ){
           // Find ending point of left subarray. mid+1 is starting
           // point of right
           int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;
           int right_end = min( left_start + 2 * curr_size - 1 , n-1);
           if( mid > n-1 ){
               mid = (left_start+right_end)/2;
           }

           // Merge Subarrays arr[left_start...mid] & arr[mid+1...right_end]
           merge(arr, left_start, mid, right_end);
       }
   }
}

/* Function to merge the two haves arr[l..m] and arr[m+1..r] of array arr[] */
void merge( char arr[][300] , int l , int m , int r )
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;
    /* create temp arrays */
    char L[n1][300] , R[n2][300];
    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        strcpy( L[i] , arr[l + i] );
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        strcpy( R[j] , arr[m + 1+ j] );
    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2){
        if ( strcmp( L[i] , R[i] ) <= 0 ){
            strcpy( arr[k] , L[i] );
            i++;
        }
        else{
            strcpy ( arr[k] , R[j] );
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there are any */
    while (i < n1){
        strcpy( arr[k] , L[i] );
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there are any */
    while (j < n2){
        strcpy( arr[k] , R[j] );
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(char  A[][300] , int size )
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d:%s \n", i , A[i]);
}
/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    FILE **openarray,*output;
    int loop,quantity;
    int tempmumber,allcheck;
    char name[300];
    quantity=20;
    int random;
    char data[quantity][300],*temp,test[300];

    printf("initial ok\n");
    for( loop = 0 ; loop < quantity ; loop++)
    {
        random = rand()%900;
        sprintf ( name ,"%d" , random );
        strcpy( data[loop] , name );
        printf("%d:%s\n",loop,data[loop]);
    }
    mergeSort( data , quantity );

    printArray( data , quantity );
    return 0;
}
```

thank for any help you can offer!

Comment: `strcmp()` is the perfect way to compare strings. The problem is almost certainly something else.

Comment: Thank you sir,I will try to debug again.

Comment: @n.m. _Does it make your computer talk Australian_ :-) :-) :-) ??? I believed that they speak (kind of) English in Australia but I live at the opposite region of globe. So, what do I know... ;-)

Comment: neither the `merge()` nor the `mergesort()` actually try to sort the array  This needs to be corrected

Comment: here is the basis for a mergesort algorithm: "Merge Sort is a Divide and Conquer algorithm. It divides input array in two halves, calls itself for the two halves and then merges the two sorted halves. The merge() function is used for merging two halves. The merge(arr, l, m, r) is key process that assumes that arr[l..m] and arr[m+1..r] are sorted and merges the two sorted sub-arrays into one. "  and here is a [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-for-merge-sort/) to an implementation of the algorithm in c

Comment: Notice that part in my prior comment about 'calls itself' to perform the sort of each partial halfs,   The posted code is not implementing the full algorithm

Answer (score 1):

It can be hard to catch small mistakes after staring at your code for too long, when this happens I recommend using a debugger and stepping through it line by line.

`strcmp( L[i] , R[i] )` should be `strcmp(L[i], R[j])`.

Comment: Thank you sir ! It's a great advice ! I will keep that in mind.And thank for the help